# Is there positive such that the inequality is true?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A\in [0,1]$ and $B\in (0,1)$, then there is small $c>0$ such that $A-cB\geq 0$.
Is the statement true ?
My way if A is not zero that is clear, cause I can choose $c=\frac{A}{B}$. Moreover, $\frac{c}{2}$. But in case $A=0$ ?

Comment: If $c\to\ 0$, then ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `linear-algebra`?

Comment: If $ A=0$ then $c$ takes on a value less than or equal to zero.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos So sorry

Comment: Then why don't you edit your question?

Comment: @Highvoltagemath But $c>0$

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, the relation $A-cB\geq 0$ is only true for $c>0$ when $A\in ( 0,1] ,\ B\in [ 0,1]$

Here it is

$ \begin{array}{l}
A-cB\geqslant 0,\\
\\
cB\leqslant A\Longrightarrow c\leqslant \frac{A}{B}\\
\\
0< c\leqslant \frac{A}{B} ,\ \frac{A}{B} \ cannot\ be\ zero\Longrightarrow A\neq 0,\ B\neq \infty ,-\infty \\
\Longrightarrow A\in ( 0,a] ,\ B\in [ b,c] ,\ where\ a,c,b\ are\ both\ finite\ numbers\ with \ a\geq0
\end{array}$

Answer (score -1):

The only way that $0-cB \geq 0$ is that either $c $ or $B $ is equal to zero (because $cB\overset{!}{=}0$).
So no, this is not possible.